# Jersey /* servlet mapping causes 404 error for static resources

Tags: java, jersey

If I map Jersey's url-pattern to /* in the 2.0 release it causes 404 for all static resources (e.g. /index.html). My web.xml has:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>JerseyApp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>org.frog.jump.JerseyApp</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JerseyApp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How do I serve static content with same url pattern?

Answer (score 29):

With Jersey 1.x you should be able to serve static content from the same path if you switch from the Jersey servlet to the filter. Drop the servlet XML you've specified and switch it to:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>org.frog.jump.JerseyApp</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
    <param-value>/.*html</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

**EDIT:** In Jersey 2.x you should be able to do the same thing but the names of the properties have been changed. Try something like:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>org.example</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
    <param-value>/.*html</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

And your POM should include:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- see. https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/ for latest version -->
```

You'll have to customize the regular expression in the init-param if you want to serve css, jsp, etc.

Another good option is to use a versioned path for your services ("/v1/*") and then static content will work without the filter.

Comment: If i am not wrong you can no longer do this in 2.x versions. com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer is not part of jersey 2.X i think.

Comment: Updated the answer to include a 2.x option. The package has changed.

Comment: Not really related maybe, but i wondered if it would be possible to set these params "programmatically" / Annotation/Properties. Seems like with JEE6 this is not possible. With JEE7 it might be, through Application.getProperites().put(key, value)?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29076059/2587435)  for another property you can set instead of the one in the above answer.

Answer (score 12):

You shall add the forwardOn404 filter to address this issue

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.bookstore.webapp.MyApplication</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.bookstore.webapp.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- pass to next filter if Jersey/App returns 404 -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

As done in this example https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/examples/bookstore-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

> **NOTE:** Make sure that you are changing the `<servlet>` configuration to a `<filter>` configuration. The Jersey [`ServletContainer`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.0.0/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.java#L132) is both an `HttpServlet` *and* a `Filter`, so you can configure it as either in your web.xml. **In order to use the `forwardOn404` property, Jersey needs to be configured as filter**.

Comment: For Jersey 1.x, its `com.sun.jersey.config.feature.FilterForwardOn404`

Comment: God bless you. :D