# Display Image with JAXWS Jersey Webservice

Tags: html, jersey, jax-rs, image

I have a java webservice (jaxws /jersey) 
and want it to display an image on the firstpage 
when I visit the webservice using the browser.

My @GET Method which's sending the html-code for the first page is as follows:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getHTMLSite(){

    String message = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"+
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"de-DE\">" +
            "<div style=\"padding-left:20px; height:200px; width:800px; font-size:20px;\">" +
                "<p>" +
                    "<h1 style=\"color:#313e7d\">" +
                        "Hello World. This is a Webservice URL" +
                    "</h1>" +
                "</p>"+
                "<img src=\"/images/img_logo.gif\" height=\"51\" width=\"537\"/>"+
            "</div>"+
            "</html>";


    return  message;
}
```

Everything is working fine except the image

```
<img src=\"/images/img_logo.gif\" height=\"51\" width=\"537\"/>
```

has not been found.

I moved the image into the WebContent / images/ directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your filter-mapping `url-pattern`? Is it `/*`?

Comment: oh well I don't even have a filter-mapping but a servlet-mapping. Servlet-mapping is set to /*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got your servlet-mapping set to `/*` Jersey is going to intercept all those requests to static resources and not know what to do with them. You could:

- Move the location of your servlet-mapping to `/api/*` or something similar. This will resolve the static resource issue but will move the end point of all your REST calls.
- Switch to the Jersey filter as described in this answer: [Jersey /* servlet mapping causes 404 error for static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422660/jersey-servlet-mapping-causes-404-error-for-static-resources/12428843#12428843)