# programmatically runnig jetty + jersey, cant publish resources

Tags: resources, jersey, jetty, executable-jar, embedded-jetty

I have a Jetty service that I run with Jetty programmatically. I have a Jetty class in the
package **package.of.my.jersey**.
I configure the server in the following way:

```
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/test");
    Map<String, Object> initMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    initMap.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    initMap.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
            "package.of.my.jersey");

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(
            new PackagesResourceConfig(initMap))), "/newValue/*");
```

I run the service via  "**java -jar nameOfTheService.jar**", and get the service works correctly for the methods that the Jersey class exposes.

I have also some HTML pages in the java/main/resources/package/of.my.jersey, and I want to access to them. The problem is that I havent find any way to access it. Is there anyway to allow other resources to run to be called via http in the same service?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's a solution for web.xml configuration but it's quite easy to replicate this configuring programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422660/jersey-servlet-mapping-causes-404-error-for-static-resources/12428843#12428843

Comment: Thank you, it is what I was searching. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: Using dropwizard makes life easier. It use Jetty for HTTP, Jersey for REST, Jackson for JSON and other good stuff for daily work.

Comment: Although this is not the answer, is more a comment, I upvoted it because it is interesting. But I guess, the answer is something else

Comment: For comment initial post i need 50 reputation ;-)

Comment: Ok,I will accept it just to have you in this site for your good advices ;)