# Spring-Boot Jersey: allow Jersey to serve static content

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

The application uses JDK 8, Spring Boot & Spring Boot Jersey starter and is packaged as a WAR (although it is locally run via Spring Boot Maven plugin).

What I would like to do is to get the documentation I generate on the fly (at build time) as a welcome page.

I tried several approaches:

1. letting Jersey serving the static contents by configuring in `application.properties` [the proper init parameter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyProperties.java#L61) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422660/jersey-servlet-mapping-causes-404-error-for-static-resources)
2. introduce a `metadata-complete=false` `web.xml` in order to list the generated HTML document as a welcome-file.

None of that worked out.

I would like to avoid having to enable Spring MVC or creating a Jersey resource just for serving a static file.

Any idea?

Here is the Jersey configuration class (I unsuccessfully tried to add a `ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX` there):

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
@ExposedApplication
@Component
public class ResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

   public ResourceConfiguration() {
      packages("xxx.api");
      packages("xxx.config");
      property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
      property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
   }
}
```

And here is Spring Boot application class (I tried adding an `application.properties` with `spring.jersey.init.jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex=/.*html` but it didn't work, I'm not exactly sure what the property key should be here):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@Import(DataConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the configuration you have used?

Comment: Just added the configuration.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let me just first state, that the reason the static content won't be served is because of the default servlet mapping of the Jersey servlet, which is `/*`, and hogs up all the requests. So the default servlet that serves the static content can't be reached. Beside the below solution, the other solution is to simply change the servlet mapping. You can do that by either annotating your `ResourceConfig` subclass with `@ApplicationPath("/another-mapping")` or set the `application.properties` property `spring.jersey.applicationPath`.

---

In regards to your first approach, take a look at the Jersey [`ServletProperties`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html). The property you are trying to configure is [`FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX). It states:

> The property is only applicable when Jersey servlet container is configured to run as a Filter, otherwise this property will be ignored

Spring Boot by default configures the Jersey servlet container as a Servlet (as mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey)):

> By default Jersey will be set up as a Servlet in a `@Bean` of type `ServletRegistrationBean` named `jerseyServletRegistration`. You can disable or override that bean by creating one of your own with the same name. **You can also use a Filter instead of a Servlet by setting `spring.jersey.type=filter`** (in which case the `@Bean` to replace or override is `jerseyFilterRegistration`).

So just set the property `spring.jersey.type=filter` in your `application.properties`, and it should work. I've tested this.

And FYI, whether configured as Servlet Filter or a Servlet, as far as Jersey is concerned, the functionality is the same.

As an aside, rather then using the `FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX`, where you need to set up some complex regex to handle all static files, you can use the [`FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404). This is actually what I used to test. I just set it up in my `ResourceConfig`

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("...");
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Héhé, just done that before reading your answer and it works! :)

Comment: Note there is still an ongoing issue with generated files. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2833 tracks the progress.

Comment: @Rolf I'm having the same issue, How exactly did you solve it ?

Comment: Remaining issue (see above) still to be addressed :/

Comment: Still not works for me, where to put my static file? How can I use a external directory ?

Comment: @peeskillet I only use boot-starter-jersey and boot-starter-data, so there is no spring-mvc. They jersey finally served my static file under static folder, but is is possible to redirect `/` to `/index.html`, BTW, I use embed tomcat.

Comment: awesome, this was very helpful!

Comment: Is there anyway we can tell jersey to ignore certain paths?

Comment: You need to also have spring-boot-starter-web to be able to serve the static content.

Comment: Thre real problem here is, that if you are using jersey starter, the default servlet implementation is NOT DispatcherServlet (org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet in my case) so if you use jersey starter, whole MVN is useless. Probably it is possible to configure it somehow, but i have no clue how.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who still can't get this to work, I followed the answer provided by @peeskillet, and had to make an additional change.

Previously I had created the following method in `Application.java`.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*");
    registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyConfig.class.getName());
    return registration;
}
```

The problem is that this registered the servlet for the `/*` path, and then setup the Jersey `ResourceConfig` configuration file.

Once I removed the above method, and placed the `@Configuration` annotation on my `ResourceConfig` class, I noticed the static resource could be retrieved via Spring Boot.

For completeness, this is a snippet of my `ResourceConfig` now.

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        // Application specific settings
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    }
}
```

[This blog post](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/01/getting-started-with-jersey-and-spring.html) was helpful in determining the difference approach for the `ResourceConfig`.

Comment: Good to mention again that in order to make the "property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);" work, we should add "spring.jersey.type: filter "  in the "application.property" file.

Answer (score 1):

Below setup worked for me

**Set**

```
spring .jersey.type: filter
```

**set** FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404

```
@Configuration 
        public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig  {

            public MyResourceConfig () {
                try {
                    register(XXX.class);
                    property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception: ", e);                   
                }
            }       

        }
```

Note: Use **@Configuration**  instead of **@component**

Comment: What kind of exceptions this try, catches?

Answer (score 0):

In our case, our project is entirely built on jersey JAX-RS so we can't use it as a filter as it breaks the whole project. So, here's what we did.

Add `spring-boot-starter-web` to your dependencies that adds spring MVC to your classpath. As spring actuator is built on MVC, you need to change the context paths.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/management
spring.jersey.application-path=/
```

1. setting the web server (tomcat) servlet context path to `/`
2. set the spring mvc servlet path to `/management` so that your actuator endpoints become `/management/actuator/health`
3. set the jersey context to `/` as usual to make your other routes work as is

Refer - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-actuator.html