# Spring boot + Jersey, Cannot find static resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, static-content

I have configured spring boot to load Jersey as a filter.

- spring.jersey.type=filter

I have set my Jersey property to allow static content:

- property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);

I have read in spring boot that I can put my content inside my resources dir, under directories named 'static', 'public' folders. Yet, I can never reach my index.html page. The only way I have gotten this to work is to create a webapp dir under src/main and put my index.html file in there.

I have tried to access the page with following urls:

- http://localhost:8080/app/index.html    <-- only works with webapp
  dir
- http://localhost:8080/app/static/index.html
- http://localhost:8080/index.html

I am using spring-boot-starter-jersey 1.3.2-Release and

Comment: Are you deploying as a war or jar?

Comment: This looks like it is related to (or a duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658240/spring-boot-jersey-allow-jersey-to-serve-static-content