# Actuator with Spring boot Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Jersey starter in my web application.

> org.springframework.boot spring-boot-starter-jersey  1.4.2.RELEASE

Trying to integrate the Actuator endpoints into my application.Used the following maven dependency

> org.springframework.boot
>         spring-boot-starter-actuator
>         1.5.2.RELEASE       
>         org.springframework.boot
>         spring-boot-starter-web
>         1.5.2.RELEASE

When I access the health endpoint, it was giving me 404 error.
http://localhost:8080/context/health

Do I need to add any other configuration class to my application that will initialize the actuator?
Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are using `/*` (default if not specified) for the Jersey mapping. The problem is that Jersey will get all the request. It does not know that it needs to forward to any actuator endpoints.

The solutions are described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670751/2587435). Either change the mapping for Jersey, or change Jersey to be used as filter instead of a servlet. Then set the Jersey property to forward requests for URLs it doesn't know.

Comment: For projects where jersey is primary servlet implementation, this worked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77680057/5123867

Answer (score 0):

This is how i was able to ti get this working

**Step 1** 
By default Jersey will be set up resource configured by extends ResourceConfig  as serverlate. We need to tell spring boot to use it as filter.
Set it as using below property

```
spring .jersey.type: filter
```

**Step 2**

I was using below configuration for registering resources

```
   @component 
    public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig  {

        public MyResourceConfig () {
            try {
                register(XXX.class);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception: ", e);                   
            }
        }       

    }
```

Change `@component` to `@Configuration` and also add below property `property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);`

**Final Configuration**

```
@Configuration 
        public class LimitResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig  {

            public LimitResourceConfig() {
                try {
                    register(XXX.class);
                    property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception: ", e);                   
                }
            }       

        }
```

Comment: This results in 404 error logs from `LoggingFeature` in console when accessing `/actuator/health`