# Spring Boot 2 Actuator endpoints inaccessible with Jersey

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, spring-boot-actuator

I have a very simple demo application using the Spring Boot 2.0.x.RELEASE

In my POM I have:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- We're using undertow as our embedded web container instead of tomcat -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Embedded web container- serves Jersey resources -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for Spring Actuator & Health Check Endpoints -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My main application just looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ResourceConfig getJerseyConfig() {
        final HashMap<String, Object> jerseyProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jerseyProperties.put(ServerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS, "json : application/json");
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig()
                .register(TestEndpoints.class);
        resourceConfig = resourceConfig.setProperties(jerseyProperties);

        return resourceConfig;
    }
}
```

When I then try and hit an actuator endpoint such as `/actuator` I receive a 404, but I can hit the endpoints in `TestEndpoints.java` with no problem. I had this working with Spring Boot 1.5.x, but now it seems that Jersey is not allowing the actuator endpoints through. If I remove the ResourceConfig bean completely, then I can hit the actuator endpoints. Is there some configuration I have to add to allow the actuator endpoints through jersey?

Comment: `/actuator/info` ?

Comment: I was able to get this working, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/56325410/320087

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because by default Jersey will use the url mapping `/*`, which will hog up all requests, including those to the actuator endpoints, which it will not find. There are two solutions; you can either change the base URL for Jersey to something else, e.g. `/api/*` or you can configure Jersey as a filter (instead of the default servlet) and set a property to make Jersey forward all requests it doesn't know down to the servlet container. Both examples can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670751/2587435).

Comment: Thanks, adding that worked. Is there a reason that prior to upgrading to SB 2/Finchley I was able to access actuator without the need for the filter and forwarding property?

Comment: I don't know. This has always been a problem, even prior to 2.0. Were you using a different base URI?

Comment: This was setup before my time, so not sure how they managed to get it working without this. But everything was under /<service>/v<version>/* and /<service>/v<version>/management/* for actuator. Which is the same setup I'm using now, just with updated versions of everything, so I don't see how it worked previously. Thanks for the help