# Actuator endpoints doesn't work without change the Jersey path

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE with Jersey, I want to use Actuator to expose the metrics of my endpoints, the problem is that it will be a new release so I don't want to change the path of my endpoints because there are already some applications using them, lets see one of them:

```
localhost:8080/employees/{employeeId}
```

In order to configure actuator with Jersey I have to make a change to my JerseyConfig class to:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig{...}
```

If I make the previous change the actuator endpoints work properly but my endpoint will be :

```
localhost:8080/api/employees/{employeeId}
```

And it will require changes in the applications that are consuming my endpoints.

**The question is how can I make the actuator endpoints work without change the Jersey's application path.**

Additional notes:

1. I'm using also jolokia to expose my metrics vía REST in order that my telegraf plugin can consume them.
2. I don't want to expose the actuator endpoints in a different port
3. The question is not duplicated because all the questions i found in Stackoverflow says that I have to change the basepath of jersey both i didn't found how to make it work without change it
4. The application will be deployed as a war file in an external tomcat

Please let me know if you need additional details

------------------------ Not duplicated question
This question is not duplicated with [Spring Boot 2 Actuator endpoints inaccessible with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620437/spring-boot-2-actuator-endpoints-inaccessible-with-jersey) because I can't change the Jersey's base path because there are already many applications consuming my endpoints so I need to change the actuator base path and make it work together with Jersey

Comment: This is not the same question, I think you didn't read the aditional notes it says that I have to change the Jersey's base path but in my question I'm saying that it doesn't work for me because I can't change the base of my endpoints so I need to change the base path of the actuator endpoint

Comment: Have you tried the **other** solution listed in that duplicate: _"or you can configure Jersey as a filter (instead of the default servlet) and set a property to make Jersey forward all requests it doesn't know down to the servlet container."_

Comment: Does not sound possible - use a reverse proxy.

Can also have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path

Comment: I'm very careful in marking duplicates. The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620437/spring-boot-2-actuator-endpoints-inaccessible-with-jersey) that I marked had _**TWO**_ solutions. The first one where you had to change the base uri is the one you did not want. And the second, as @MarkRotteveel mentioned where need to change Jersey to a Filter and set a property was another one. What you want is the second one.

Comment: I still think that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620437/spring-boot-2-actuator-endpoints-inaccessible-with-jersey?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Did you actually try that second solution (it works, I know it works, because I have had to apply it myself in a project).