# I have 2 types of resources in my SPRINGBOOT app:JAX-RX controller and spring RestController,I'm not able to reach to spring RestController resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I have a springboot application where I have used two types of controllers for apis:

1. Jersey controller using `@Path("/v1/test")` and `@Service` combination
2. Spring Rest Controller using `@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz/")` and `@RestController` combination

I have kept jersey application path as blank
spring.jersey.application-path=

Whenever I try to reach to /xyz uri, it is giving me 404 not found error. It tries to look for the uri under all jersey resources and if it doesn't find it there, it gives 404 not found error.

I have tried two things:

1. I tried to give some random path to jersey application path like below:
   spring.jersey.application-path=abc
   In this case it is able to distinguish between two types of controllers so I was able to reach to **/abc/v1/test** as well as **/xyz**
2. I created **/xyz** in jersey controller and deleted it from spring rest controller, and I have kept jersey application path as blank. In this case also I am able to reach to both the apis.

But I want neither of the options. How can I configure springboot so that if any resources are not found in jersey controller, it should look for spring rest controller and I can still keep **spring.jersey.application-path** property blank.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670751/2587435

Comment: This answer doesn't Help Paul, I want to keep the property spring.jersey.application-path property blank.

Comment: I believe the second part of the answer will solve your problem. You do not need to change the Jersey root path with this option.