# JerseyConfig overrides @RestController in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to use `JerseyConfig` class in existing sping boot application but for some reason when I add this configuration:

```
    @Component
    public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig  {
    public JerseyConfig() {
         register(Users.class);
         register(Groups.class);
         property("SCIM_IMPLEMENTATION_INSTANCE", new JerseyApplication());
      }
    }
```

The @RestController endpoints do not work as expexted anymore. All of them return 404 after applying this `JerseyConfig` class. All of the Jersey endpoints work fine.

Can I use JAX rs endpoints (in my case I use Jersey) and @RestCotroller in the same application? I need some configuration for separating my existing REST servcices from the new JAX rs endpoints. If anybody can help I will really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: [Same reason, same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670751/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for combining Jersey resources and Spring controllers. There are a couple of changes that you will need to do to your setup.

1. Change annotation of JerseyConfig from `@Component` to `@Configuration` and add package of your controllers to scan

   `// scan the resources package for your resources / restControler
   public JerseyConfig()
   {
       // other code
       packages(package_of_your_rest_controller);
   }`
2. Change annotation of your rest controller from `@ReuestMapping` to `@Path`
   E.g. if your controller is like this:

   @RestController
   @Component
   public class MyRestController {

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/foo")
   public String foo() {
       return "foo";
   }
   ```

   }

   It becomes this:

   @Path("/")
   @Component
   public class MyRestController {

   ```
   @Path("/foo")
   public String foo() {
       return "foo";
   }
   ```

   }

Give this a try once if you can.

Comment: Hello :) thanks for your answer! The thing I did is adding `@ApplicationPath("/path")`
to `ResourceConfig` class and it worked fine!