# Serving static content in Spring Boot with Jetty and Jersey

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0

I'm running a Spring Boot application with `Jetty` server. The APIs are served by the `Jersey servlet`. The static contents are placed in `src/main/static` and `src/main/private-static`.

**Issue#1** Static content in `src/main/static` is not being served

The content in `src/main/static` is public and can be accessed freely. According to this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content Spring boot should automatically serve the static content, but it does not.

**Issues#2** How to set the static content directory to `src/main/private-static` for this custom servlet that checks for authentication before serving a file.

I've created another `servlet` to serve static content *with authentication*

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> privateStaticContent() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new HttpServlet() {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
            int status = isAuthenticated(req) ? 200 : 401;

            resp.setStatus(status);
        }
    }, "/private-static/*");
}
```

Basically this servlet should serve files from the directory `src/main/private-static`, but I'm not sure how and where to configure this.

**Issue#3** To make Jersey serve at `/api` endpoint, I've added this in `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

But this makes all the servlets to use this `/api` endpoint. How can I configure this only for Jersey servlet and not for others. Is there something like `server.servlet.jersey.context-path=/api` ?

Comment: Issue #3, the property is not correct. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670751/2587435

Answer (score 0):

`src/main/java/<dir>/<static-content>` is not something that maven or gradle would ever see.

the `src/main/java` tree is only used for `*.java`, nothing else.

perhaps you should be using `src/main/resources/<dir>/<static-content>` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I made a typo in my question. I corrected it. Thank you

Comment: Have you specifically configured gradle or maven for `src/main/static` or `src/main/private-static`? As those are also not used by maven/gradle, and content within those directories won't be found by your classes.  If you are packaging for jar, use `src/main/resources/static` or if you are packaging for war use `src/main/webapp/static`