# Spring Boot static resources html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jersey

I created a spring  starter project, but i can't access the static resource

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJk41.png)

Application

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application10_4 extends ResourceConfig{

     public Application10_4(){
            register(new BookService10_4());
        }
       
        public static void main(String[] args){
            SpringApplication.run(Application10_4.class, args);
        }
}
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZh7W.png)

when I use the self-generated application  I can access static resources

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I corrected the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670751/2587435

Answer (score 0):

What is it `register(new BookService10_4());` ?

Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

```
/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static/
/public/
```

So you can create a `public/` directory under `resources/` directory and put your static contents there. And they will be reached by: http://localhost:3000/koo.htm. (assuming the server.port is 3000)

You can customize these directories using `spring.resources.static-locations` in the `application.properties`.

You can continue read in https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot