# Jersey Viewable resulting in 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, jersey

I am attempting to create a RESTful web service in Java using Jersey and Tomcat. The problem I am having is that after authenticating a user, I try to return a Response with a Viewable containing the path to my file and I receive a 404 resource not found error.

I have tried every possible path I can think of, including adding multiple copies of map.jsp in the root, WEB-INF and in child folders of WEB-INF. I have also tried omitting the .jsp when returning the Response with the Viewable with no luck.

My folder structure looks like this:

- Web Pages

  - map.jsp
  - META-INF

    - context.xml
  - WEB-INF

    - map.jsp
    - jsp

      - map.jsp
      - web.xml

The method below is called once authorization is complete. I have verified this by returning the String "hello world" which does display. Here is the code I currently have for my Resource class.

```
@Path("/")
public class WebServiceResource
{
    private static final UserDao USER_DAO = new UserDao();
    private static final Logger log =  Logger.getLogger(WebServiceResource.class.getName());

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getJSP()
    {
        log.log(Level.ALL, "getJSP() method: ");
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("map.jsp")).build();
    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-webservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.company.mywebservice.ws.WebServiceApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;com.company.mywebservice.ws.Authorization</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
             <param-value>/(resources|(WEB-INF))/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my-webservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Jersey need s to be registered as a filter for `com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex` to work. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12428843/2587435)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this issue, here's the solution, courtesy of the link provided by peeskillet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428843/2587435). My issue was that I was missing the following dependency, though mine was a different version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-m07-1</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

After adding that dependency to my pom everything worked.