# How can I have one java app serving faces and direct resources at the same time?

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey

I'm currently working on a project, which serves different faces in the localhost:8080/myapp/faces/ subdirectory using a Faces servlet (see web.xml:)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My plan now is to have another directory accessible via localhost:8080/myapp/secondapp/. There I'd like to place some plain html files, css resources etc. as it will be an Angular app.

I just added the directory "secondapp" including an "index.html" in my /src/main/webapp folder, but I can't access it via localhost:8080/myapp/secondapp/index.html directly. I already did a clean redeploy of the app, but it just won't work.

How do I need to change my web.xml or other files to get this running in glassfish with jersey to be able to access all files in the "secondapp" directory via simple GET requests?

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Comment: What's your URL pattern for your Jersey app? Is it `/*`?

Comment: Yes, all the other jersey and javax.ws.rs stuff is running at `/*`. But no other servlets are mapped in the `web.xml`.

Comment: What does `/*` mean do you think?

Comment: Actually I want to know whether it's possible to easily have the jersey app return a specific folder under a specific end point without changing the `/*`. If there's no other solution than creating another java app, then I go for it ;)

Comment: You're going to want to look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12422660/2587435) then. Note the key with the solutions is to configure Jersey as a filter.

Comment: Thx, peeskillet. That works perfect and was exactly the modification I was looking for.