# how serve dynamic html with spring boot and jersey?

Tags: java, html, spring, maven, jersey

I'm using spring boot and jersey and I have write the API, but now I need to serve a dinamic html page.
I have add to my pom.xml this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
<version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have an html in

> /resources/templates/file.html

and in my endpoint class `return Response.ok(new Viewable("/file.html")).build();` but not work.

Comment: How is it going to be dynamic if you aren't using a template engine? Check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31900846/2587435)

Comment: I tried but it does not work

Comment: What doesn't work? What's happening? Please update your post to show _exactly_ what you did, and I will try to help