# How to place html files in a Java Dynamic Web Project as a REST service using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest

I created a Dynamic Web Project in Java using Eclipse JEE to make a REST web service. I am trying to add a html file simply to add a form that allows me to test my web services in a faster and easier way.

I have read that just placing the html files under the `WebContent` folder or the `WEB-INF` folder does the trick. But since I already have a `web.xml` file it's disrupting the expected behaviour:

This is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST web service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ws,com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST web service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So where should I place my html files and what should I modify in my `web.xml` file to get it working (if it needs to be modified)?

Comment: Maybe a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12422660/2587435)

Comment: may be all your requests are going to the reset web service.. try instead of <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> a pattern like <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>

Comment: @awesome and how should I set up my web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `web.xml` you have a mapping for `/*` which means that the `REST web service` will receive all the connections, you can either make `REST web service` return the appropriate resource based on the url or change its mapping (`<url-pattern>`) to something more specific.

Comment: could you give me an example of how I could set that up?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do, the simplest way to resolve this will be to change the mapping in the `web.xml` file to something like this `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>`