# Serve static content in root of Jersey HttpServlet on Tomcat 7

Tags: html, tomcat, servlets, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am implementing an API with Jersey 2.22.2, with the following exemplary GET URL:

`http://example.com/api/users`

Calling this URL returns, e.g., a list of users in JSON.

Now I want to be able to serve static content from the URL root, i.e.,

`http://example.com/api/`

I've included a simple *index.html* file in `/webapps/`, next to `WEB-INF`, and it gets built into the root of the WAR successfully.

However, when I navigate to `http://example.com/api/` or `http://example.com/api/index.html`, I get a 404.

How can I configure `web.xml` or the servlet itself, to serve static content from the app root?

Comment: Why would you want the static content from `/api`? It's not part of the API. It should be served from `example.com/index.html`. That's the root. If `/api`, is your context path, it shouldn't be. Your context path should be nothing. `/api` should be the servlet mapping for the Jersey application.

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks. Yes, context root is nothing. I wanted to serve API documentation at /api. Or is this something where you would usually return hypermedia with a link to an external folder like /docs?

Comment: You should put the docs in the `/api` folder in the `webapps`. Then you need to [configure Jersey to forward the request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12422660/2587435).

Comment: You _could_ just use a Jersey resource to serve it, but you want to take advantage of the caching done by the server's default servlet. Doing it this way make's Jersey forward the unknown requests to the default servlet.