# Serve static files together with Jersey, Guice config

Tags: jersey, jetty, guice, guice-servlet

I do have the following configuration as a Guice module (instead of a web.xml)

```
public class RestModule extends JerseyServletModule {
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    install(new JpaPersistModule("myDB"));
    filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);

    bind(CustomerList.class);
    bind(OrdersList.class);

    bind(MessageBodyReader.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    bind(MessageBodyWriter.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);

    ImmutableMap<String, String> settings = ImmutableMap.of(
            JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, "true"
            );

    serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, settings);
}
}
```

Serving the REST endpoints does work very well already.

I would like to serve a static html file from /webapp/index.html when the user requests http://example.com/

and the rest services at http://example.com/customers or http://example.com/orders

i do not use a web.xml. the webserver is jetty

Comment: i am aware that there is a similar answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808610/serving-static-content-with-jetty-jersey-guice but i really want to avoind having /services/ prefixed

Comment: Andreas, did you find a solution to this?  I've been struggling with this for multiple hours now.  I've tried everything from serveRegex with various regex posted in the guice community, to this solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3593513/695318) to using tuckey UrlRewriteFilter and I've failed every time.  Finally, I found condit's post thanks to your question and it's working perfectly fine. If you've used another solution, I'd be curious to how you solved it.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Jersey /* servlet mapping causes 404 error for static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422660/jersey-servlet-mapping-causes-404-error-for-static-resources/12428843#12428843)
and add the appropriate parameters to your `settings` object. Something like:

```java
ImmutableMap<String, String> settings = ImmutableMap.of(
  JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, "true"
  "com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex", "/.*html");
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, I've struggled with this nearly all day.  condit linked to the correct answer, but for completeness here's what worked for me.  I'm using Tomcat, jersey (and jersey-guice) 1.17.1, and guice 3.0.

Though I'm using Tomcat, the difficult part (serving static resources) shouldn't be that different.

```
public class JerseyConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {

                // Bind  REST resources
                bind(HomeController.class);
                bind(AboutController.class);

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex",
                    "/(images|css)/.*");
                filter("/*").through(GuiceContainer.class, params);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: the last two lines are the most important.

First, the param to ignore static files:

```
"com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex" (1.7 only!!!)
```

I have this set to the regex:

```
"/(images|css)/.*"
```

...since my static resources are located at src/main/webapp/images and src/main/webapp/css (I'm using the maven project structure).  So for instance:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/images/logo.png
```

(this is for jersey 1.7.x only - if you're using jersey 2.x, you should use the key "jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex" or ideally the Java constant ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX).

Finally, the last line:

```
filter("/*").through(GuiceContainer.class, params);
```

You should use: filter("/*").through and NOT serve("/*).with

If you came up with a different solution, I'd like to see what it was.